# Hangout App Instance for Multiple Users

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

I wrote a Google Hangout app that allows me to track basic information of the hangout, mostly whether or not it is still alive.

The first user starts the hangout (which also loads my hangout app), I pull the hangoutURL, and share it with another user who then joins the hangout as well.

The problem is that the app dies when that first user leaves the hangout, and I can no longer track the hangout.

Is there a way for the app to be loaded for each participant so that it isn't tied to that first user? I was thinking one solution would be that you could include the gid in the hangoutURL somehow for the second user, but couldn't find documentation on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're spot on with your potential solution. You can add the gid parameter (along with the gd parameter, if you wish) to the URL for the hangout video chat, the same way you use the gid and gd parameters on the raw URL to bootstrap the hangout video chat.

Comment: Thanks! Will try that out first thing in the morning. Watched your YouTube video earlier in the week btw, and it was very helpful.